# Does Pymongo have validation rules built in?

Tags: mongodb, validation, pymongo

I am trying to validate an inserted document against a schema, and was trying to find a way to validate the inserted document.

There are libraries like `MongoEngine` that say they do the work, but is there a way to do document validation directly via `pymongo` ?

Comment: FYI: reading validation rules using pymongo: `db.get_collection('test').options().get('validator')`

Answer (score 21):

The python driver docs are indeed a little light on how to use the `db.command`.   Here is a complete working example:

```
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    from collections import OrderedDict
    import sys
    
    client = MongoClient()   # supply connection args as appropriate 
    db = client.testX
    
    db.myColl.drop()
    
    db.create_collection("myColl")  # Force create!
    
    #  $jsonSchema expression type is prefered.  New since v3.6 (2017):
    vexpr = {"$jsonSchema":
      {
             "bsonType": "object",
             "required": [ "name", "year", "major", "gpa" ],
             "properties": {
                "name": {
                   "bsonType": "string",
                   "description": "must be a string and is required"
                },
                "gender": {
                   "bsonType": "string",
                   "description": "must be a string and is not required"
                },
                "year": {
                   "bsonType": "int",
                   "minimum": 2017,
                   "maximum": 3017,
                   "exclusiveMaximum": False,
                   "description": "must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
                },
                "major": {
                   "enum": [ "Math", "English", "Computer Science", "History", None ],
                   "description": "can only be one of the enum values and is required"
                },
                "gpa": {
                   # In case you might want to allow doubles OR int, then add
                   # "int" to the bsonType array below:
                   "bsonType": [ "double" ],
                   "minimum": 0,
                   "description": "must be a double and is required"
                }
             }
      }
    }
    
    # Per the docs, args to command() require that the first kev/value pair
    # be the command string and its principal argument, followed by other
    # arguments.  There are two ways to do this:  Using an OrderDict:
    cmd = OrderedDict([('collMod', 'myColl'),
            ('validator', vexpr),
            ('validationLevel', 'moderate')]
    db.command(cmd)
    
    # Or, use the kwargs construct:
    # db.command('collMod','myColl', validator=vexpr, validationLevel='moderate')

    try:
        db.myColl.insert({"x":1})
        print "NOT good; the insert above should have failed."
    except:
        print "OK. Expected exception:", sys.exc_info()    
    
    try:
        okdoc = {"name":"buzz", "year":2019, "major":"Math", "gpa":3.8}
        db.myColl.insert(okdoc)
        print "All good."
    except:
        print "exc:", sys.exc_info()
```

Comment: Life saving code ...

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB supports document validation at the engine level so you'll pick it up via pymongo.   You declare your "schema" (rules actually) to the engine.   Here's a great place to start:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/

Comment: You're partly right. MongoDB offers builtin validation, but unfortunately validation is not stated anywhere in `pymongo`'s documentation

Comment: any chance anyone can add an example for this? I'm really struglling with it!

Comment: Yeah that’s what I was looking for, but I solved it by just using mongo engine ORM

Answer (score 1):

You can make a separated JSON file for your Document Validations Schema, like this:

```
    {
      "collMod": "users",
      "validator": {
        "$jsonSchema": {
          "bsonType": "object",
          "required": ["email", "password","name"],
          "properties": {
            "email": {
              "bsonType": "string",
              "description": "Correo Electrónico"
            },
            "password": {
              "bsonType": "string",
              "description": "Una representación Hash de la contraseña"
            },
            "name": {
              "bsonType": "object",
              "required": ["first", "last"],
              "description": "Objeto que separa los nombres y apellidos",
              "properties":  {
                "first": {
                  "bsonType": "string",
                  "description": "Primer y segundo nombre"
                },
                "last": {
                  "bsonType": "string",
                  "description": "Primer y segundo apellido"
                }
              }
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Then you can use in python script, example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json #parse JSON  file as dict
from collections import OrderedDict #preserve the order (key, value) in the gived insertions on the dict

client = MongoClient("your_mongo_uri")
db = client.your_db_name 

with open('your_schema_file.json', 'r') as j:
    d = json.loads(j.read())

d = OrderedDict(d)

db.command(d)
```

[OrderedDict Info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordereddict-in-python/)

[collMod Info](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collMod/#validationAction)

[Schema Validation Info](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 options to deal with:

1. By creating or setting schema for collection, so any insertions will be checked against it on server side, rejected or warned depending on [validationAction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/schema-validation/#accept-or-reject-invalid-documents)
   The following code demonstrates scheme creation and testing:

```py
import pymongo

mongo_client = MongoClient(url=...,
                          port=...,
                          username=...,
                          password=...,
                          authSource=...,
                          authMechanism=...,
                          connect=True, )
mongo_client.server_info()
db = mongo_client.your_db
users = db.create_collection(name="users",
                             validator={"$jsonSchema": {
                                 "bsonType": "object",
                                 "required": ["username"],
                                 "properties": {
                                     "username": {
                                         "bsonType": "string",
                                         "pattern": "[a-z0-9]{5,15}",
                                         "description": "user name (required), only lowercase letters "
                                                        "and digits allowed, from 5 to 15 characters long"
                                     },
                                     "email": {
                                         "bsonType": "string",
                                         "description": "User's email (optional)"
                                     },
                                 }
                             }},
                             validationAction="error",
                             )
# Inserting user document that fits the scheme
users.insert_one({"username": "admin", "email": "some_admin_mail"})
# Insertion below will be rejected with "pymongo.errors.WriteError: Document failed validation, full error"
# caused by too short username (root)
users.insert_one({"username": "root", "email": "some_root_mail"})
```

2. You can think about your Mongo's documents as ordinary JSON entities and check them on the client code side using standard [JSON scheme](https://json-schema.org/) validation

```py
from jsonschema import validate
from jsonschema.exceptions import ValidationError

db = MongoClient(...).your_db
schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["username"],
    "properties": {
        "username": {"type": "string", "pattern": "[a-z0-9]{5,15}"},
        "email": {"type": "string"},
    },
}
try:
    new_user = {"username": "admin", "email": "some_admin_mail"}
    # No exception will be raised in validation below
    validate(instance=new_user, schema=schema)
    db.users.insert_one(new_user)

    new_user = {"username": "root", "email": "some_root_mail"}
    # Exception <ValidationError: 'root' does not match '[a-z0-9]{5,15}'> will be raised
    validate(instance=new_user, schema=schema)
    db.users.insert_one(new_user)
except ValidationError:
    # Performing error
```