# Does pymongo support json schema validation?

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, jsonschema

In MongoDB 3.6 one can specify a json schema to validate documents in a collection, but I haven't seen anything like that in pymongo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

- For adding json schema at the time you create the collection, I haven't seen any good method to do it with pymongo.
- By if you want to attach a schema to existing collections, please refer to
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51520384/10189759